# Python drop rows lower than a time for the first day of dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

I have a column of type datetime64[ns] (df.start_date). I want to drop all rows until a certain time of the first date. For example, having data from `2022-05-03 00:00:00` to `2022-06-03 17:00:00`, I want my dataset to just start from `2022-05-03 17:00:00` (note time changed but date is the same).

I tried this:

```
first = pd.to_datetime('2022-05-03').date() 
hour = pd.to_datetime('17:00:00').time() 
df = df[~(df['start_date'].dt.date == first & df['start_date'].dt.time < hour)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

But got error

```
TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool]
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each condition needs its own pair of parentheses like so:

```
first = pd.to_datetime('2022-05-03').date() 
hour = pd.to_datetime('17:00:00').time() 
df = df[~((df['start_date'].dt.date == first) & (df['start_date'].dt.time < hour))].reset_index(drop=True)
```

or more simply:

```
df = df[df['start_date'] >= pd.Timestamp('2022-05-03 17:00:00')]
```